# Is it possible to foreach or check if it contains a certain text in HttpFileCollection.FileName? - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I am trying to upload a certain files with names like '2018-2-10 10-23-34' // February 10, 2018 10:23:34, this is not a one file only, I have like multiple files with names like these. That's why I use HttpFileCollection.

Now, for example that I selected files with file names like these, I want to check if it has the right file name, else it will just SaveAs as it is.

As you can see below, I added a fake code, its fake since its not working or it has a wrong syntax in it.

I saw a code like this, but I don't know how to apply this on my current code with HttpFileCollection, please help.

```
bool contains  = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any(f => f.Contains("three"));
```

**My Code**

```
 protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d");
                     DateTime DateValue;
                     DateValue = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                     string dayoftheweek = "(" + DateValue.ToString("dddd") + ")";
                     Response.Write(dayoftheweek);
                    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
                    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                    {
                        foreach (hfc[i].FileName.Contains(date))// What I am trying to do, but wrong syntax or wrong code
                        {
                                hfc[i].SaveAs(@path+"\\" + hfc[i].FileName + dayoftheweek);
                        }// What I am trying to do, but wrong syntax or wrong code
                        Response.Write(hfc[i].FileName);

                        hfc[i].SaveAs(@path+"\\" + hfc[i].FileName);

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop is wrong as you mentioned.

```
//This will make you iterate trough the file collection
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
     if(hfc[i].FileName.Contains(date))
     {
        hfc[i].SaveAs(@path+"\\" + hfc[i].FileName + dayoftheweek);
     }      
}
```

The foreach loop is not needed anymore so you can remove

```
foreach (hfc[i].FileName.Contains(date))
{
}
```

Comment: @ChristianQuirante Fixed it it has to be myFile.FileName.Contains

Comment: it gives me a new error, object doesn't contain method for FileName. I don't know what to change with 'var' to make it work

Comment: I changed it the other way arround for you. this should work sorry didnt know it didnt give back any object. Tested this and does whats asked for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your for each loop doesnt have a declaration

```
foreach(var variable in Enumerable){
 //other code 
}
```

so in your case it would be

```
foreach( var file in hfc)
{
 //other code
}
```

and it should work just fine